# How to get rid of some meshes in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting

I have some data that needs to be represented using the function ListDensityPlot, for example :

```
data = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 3}, {5, 1, 4}, {6, 4, 5}}
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

And this gives :

[image]

However, if we show the meshes using this code :

```
data = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 3}, {5, 1, 4}, {6, 4, 5}}
ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> All]
```

It shows this :

[image]

How can i specify ListDensityPlot to only Plot within the data point, and not plot the region delimited by the triangle {1,1},{2,3},{1,4} (the one on the left side} ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is that triangle different than the other triangles where data is given at all of the vertices?

Comment: because listdensityplot gives me a a polygon with 4 edges when the result is 5 edges. Same goes for my actual data, i have an n sided polygon when i actually want something like n+10

Answer (score 3):

Use the option [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html)

```
data = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 3}, {5, 1, 4}, {6, 4, 5}};

ListDensityPlot[data, Mesh -> All,
 RegionFunction ->
  (Not[{#1, #2} \[Element] Triangle[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {1, 4}}]] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much ! it does exactly what i need it to do !